# Angular 2 - add custom class to top item for submenu item chosen

Tags: angular

I use a third part library with visual components. The menu is build as flat ul/li/a:

```
<ul class="abs-nav abc-left">
    <li><a [routerLink]="['Dashboard']">Dashboard</a></li>
    <li><a [routerLink]="['SystemInformation']">System information</a></li>
    <li><a [routerLink]="['Health']">Health</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-dropdown="#tasks-menu" dropdown-position='right'>Tasks</a></li>
</ul>
```

and submenu are added as separate lists and then they are glued in JS.

```
<ul id="tasks-menu" class="abc-dropdown">
    <li><a [routerLink]="['TasksUpdate']">Update</a></li>
    <li><a [routerLink]="['TasksDeployment']">Deployment</a></li>
</ul>
```

I've added css which marks chosen item from top level menu (adding background color to `.abc-nav li a.router-link-active`.

I need to add `router-link-active` class to *Tasks* menu when one of its subitems is chosen.

I've found those SOs: 
[In Angular 2 how do I assign a custom class to an active router link?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34965853/in-angular-2-how-do-i-assign-a-custom-class-to-an-active-router-link) , [Changing the default name of "router-link-active" class by writing a custom directive that adds new class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36537878/changing-the-default-name-of-router-link-active-class-by-writing-a-custom-dire)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this question: [angular2-how-to-use-an-or-statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37378425/angular2-how-to-use-an-or-statement).

Basically what you need is:

```
<li>
    <a href="#" data-dropdown="#tasks-menu" dropdown-position='right'
       [class.router-link-active]="currentPath.indexOf('Tasks') !== -1">
        Tasks
    </a>
</li>
```

Current path can be retrieved from location e.g.:

```
class MyController {
    currentPath: string;

    constructor(private location: Location, private router: Router) {
        this.router.subscribe((val) => {
            this.currentPath = location.path();
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I have `currentPath` undefined

Comment: Hi, check my update. Of course you need to keep your current route in the 'currentPath' parameter. Easiest is to subscribe to router changes.